# How to reverse an intersection segment in TikZ (not pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

In a way, this is just a reminder of an [old unsolved question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287401/121799) but arguably with some new insight or tilt. (And I do not think the actual question is a duplicate of the old one.) The `fillbetween` library has the feature of providing access to intersection segments. I am aware of [Heiko Oberdiek's statement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383766/121799) that this might be not always precise, but I find that in many cases it is actually precise enough. IMHO the real problem is that `reverse` does not work in plain Ti*k*Z, while in pgfplots it just [works fine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405485/121799). Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,fillbetween} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[name path = line1, draw] (-1,0) to[out=90,in=90] (1,1) to[out=-90,in=0]  (0,-1);
    \path[name path = line2, draw] (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
    \draw[very thick, intersection segments={of=line1 and line2,sequence=L2}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[name path = line1, draw] (-1,0) to[out=90,in=90] (1,1) to[out=-90,in=0]  (0,-1);
    \path[name path = line2, draw] (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
    \draw[very thick, intersection segments={of=line1 and line2,sequence=L1 R2}];
\end{tikzpicture}

% The following does not work.
% 
% \begin{tikzpicture}
%     \path[name path = line1, draw] (-1,0) to[out=90,in=90] (1,1) to[out=-90,in=0]  (0,-1);
%     \path[name path = line2, draw] (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
%     \draw[very thick, intersection segments={of=line1 and
%   line2,sequence=L2[reverse] R2}];
% \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I were to uncomment the last part, I'd trigger an error. In fact, any attempt to make `reverse` work lead to an error.

**QUESTION**: Is there a (simple) way to fix this?

**COMMENT**: Once `reverse` works, the [old unsolved question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287401/121799) should be solved as well.

Comment: Just add brace around `L2[reverse] R2`  -> `{L2[reverse] R2}`

Comment: pgfplots samples the path, tikz produces a standalone path. The segment marking is find the intersections points and converting into timer values.

Comment: @SalimBou Seems to work. Want to shoot an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are using seems to be wrong.  See the `pgfplots` manual which has examples such as

```
\fill [
        intersection segments={
            of=f and border,
            sequence={R2[reverse] -- L2}},
        pattern=north west lines,
]
    -- (rel axis cs:1,1) -- cycle;
```

in the explanation of the `reverse` (currently page 444 in Chapter 5),
and notice that the `sequence` argument is contained in braces `{...}`.

The document
below, corresponding to you last non-working code, works fine with this change:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[name path = line1, draw] (-1,0) to[out=90,in=90] (1,1)
    to[out=-90,in=0]  (0,-1);
  \path[name path = line2, draw] (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
  \draw[very thick, intersection segments={of=line1 and line2,
    sequence={L2[reverse] R2}}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```